# capistrano: sudo error after after it had been working fine before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, capistrano

I recently started using capistrano in my rails application deployment.  It was working fine for me and then all of a sudden, I started getting this error

```
sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

after every gem it tried to install.  I know this problem can typically be solved by putting in set `:use_sudo, false` in the deploy.rb file but I already have that in there.  And the strangest thing is that I reverted my ENTIRE directory back to when I know for sure capistrano was working and it's still giving me the same error.

My server is running CentOS

So what could the problem possibly be caused by?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can tell cap to create a pty for each process, by adding this line:

`default_run_options[:pty] = true`

to `Capfile`

Answer (score 1):

For Capistrano 3 you need to add:

`set :pty, true`

to the file `config/deploy.rb`

Comment: will it prompt for a password? I tried that and when i type its clearly showing the password.

Comment: I use SSH keys not a password

Comment: well i have setup SSH keys too. It asks for password for the following `Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=/home/deployer/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env sudo ln -nfs /home/deployer/apps/managewise_production/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ )`.

Comment: what if i want to use a command with sudo. such as creating symlinks for nginx? How would i do that

Comment: See also this: http://blog.zenlinux.com/2008/02/centos-5-configuration-tweak-for-sudo/